# How to add subtitle to .mp4 videos in android?

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, subtitle

I'm using video-url to play video in android and now i want to read subtitle (.srt) from url. I searched on the internet and i found two solution but is useless for me. One of the solution was in the github ; https://github.com/NineWorlds/serenity-android.git , but i couldn't find the library or i did not understand how can i use it. The other solution was fetching srt from res/raw folder but i need to fetch and read srt file from url. The question is not duplicate. I'm looking for complete and clear example.

I'm playing video from url :

```
  private class Videoexec extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            Intent getint = getIntent();
            String link = getint.getStringExtra("Video_URL");
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    VideoActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                videoview.start();
            }
        });
    }}..
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: You can use video player libraries like Exoplayer. It have better support over android VideoView. ( For ref - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57818867/8731069 )